# Twitter + Delicious?

Tags: twitter, delicious

Okay, I may be revealing my ignorance here, but I can't seem to find an answer.  I recently got a Delicious account.  However, I post a lot of links on Twitter as well.  I hardly ever post to both.  The result?  When I want to find previous links/bookmarks, it's often more hassle than it's worth.

So my question: *Is there any way to search my Twitter/Delicious links at the same time?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Trunk.ly](http://trunk.ly/)**

[Greplin](http://www.greplin.com/) is great, but Delicious isn't supported yet ("coming soon").